# How can i modify date inside json object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i modify value inside object?

For example from this object that contain total of days

```
const data = {
"A": [{
         id: 1,
         day: 12
     },{
         id: 2,
         day: 14
     }]
 }
```

And add 1 day to day object to become something like this

```
const data = {
"A": [{
         id: 1,
         day: 13
     },{
         id: 2,
         day: 15
     }]
 }
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Comment: Does this one-liner do what you want — `Object.values(data).forEach((array) => array.forEach((obj) => ++obj.day));`? Note that it mutates the original `data` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.A.forEach(item => item.day++);
```

Working snippet:

```js
const data = { A: [{ id: 1, day: 12 }, { id: 2, day: 14 }] };

data.A.forEach(item => item.day++);

console.log(data)
```

Or, if you don't want to mutate data:

```
const newData = { A: data.A.map(item => ({id: item.id, day: item.day + 1})) }
```

Working snippet:

```js
const data = { A: [{ id: 1, day: 12 }, { id: 2, day: 14 }] };

const newData = {
  A: data.A.map(item => ({ id: item.id, day: item.day + 1 }))
}

console.log(newData)
```